# Spring Oauth2RestTemplate error "access_denied"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I need to consume a OAuth2 Rest service with ClientCredential Grant.

I'm using spring security and spring oauth2.

To get the access token i need to call the token uri passing to it a *clientId* and a *password*

Basically i need to send a POST with this body

```
{"clientId":"demo",
"password": "demo_password"
}
```

and I should get something like that in the response

```
{
    "expiresIn": 3600,
    "accessToken": "EF2I5xhL2GU9pAwK",
    "statusCode": 200,
    "refreshToken": "72BIcYWYhPjuPDGb"
}
```

I was trying to configure OAuth2RestTemplate in this way

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class RestTemplateConf {

    @Value("${ApiClient}")
    private String oAuth2ClientId;

    @Value("${ApiSecret}")
    private String oAuth2ClientSecret;

    @Value("${ApiUrl}")
    private String accessTokenUri;


    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuthRestTemplate() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setClientId(oAuth2ClientId);
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret(oAuth2ClientSecret);
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        resourceDetails.setTokenName("accessToken");


        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext());

        return restTemplate;
    }


}
```

but i get always

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is error="access_denied", error_description="Error requesting access token."] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
```

If i make a POST call to the tokenUri with POSTMAN, for instance, i get the token correctly...

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm also facing same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989458/org-springframework-security-oauth2-common-exceptions-invalidgrantexception-bad